# saving optimization steps to a file

Tags: python, scipy

I try to use the Powell’s method for the minimization a function. However, I encountered an issue firth saving optimization steps to a file.
This is the general concept what I did so far:

```
def printx(coeff):
    global fout
    fout.write(coeff)

func = 'TEST'
fout = open(func +'.txt','w')
opt_res = opt.fmin_powell(engine, coeff, args=(func,func), callback=printx,disp=1)
fout.close()
```

I am getting in return a TEST.txt file with wired symbols:

```
`¯q^Y^T´^L@`¯q^Y^T´^L@`¯q^Y^T´^L@`¯q^Y^T´^L@
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but there are a lot of interesting, not idiomatic things here. If `opt.fmin_powell` really expects a function that relies on a global file descriptor like that, I'd be very surprised.

Comment: Also, try `open(..., 'a')`. `'w'` is for writing a new file (i.e., overwriting the contents of the file), `'a'` is for appending to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `write` [must be a string](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Cleaning up your code a little bit:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    callback = lambda x: f.write(str(x))
    opt_res = opt.fmin_powell(engine, coeff, args=(func,func), callback=callback, disp=1)
```